# How to do a data occurance search on a MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, search, lookup

I am very new in MySQL & PHP. 
I have 2 tables like these with more than thousands of row.

```
Table "Company A" 
id | Date       | Prize_1   | Prize_2   | Prize_3 | Prize_Consolation
1  | 2011-01-13 | "car"     | "ipad2"   | "bag"   | "mouse" 
2  | 2011-02-13 | "ps3"     | "iphone4" | "mouse" | "bag"

Table "Company B" 
id | Date       | Prize_1   | Prize_2   | Prize_3 | Prize_Consolation 
1  | 2011-01-18 | "tv"      | "iphone4" | "ipod"  | "bag" 
2  | 2011-02-13 | "iphone4" | "ipad"    | "bag"   | "mouse"
```

User will randomly send query to search history information on a 'prize' when and which company was issued.

Example: I would like to do a query search on both tables for the prize "**iphone4**" and it should return results something like this:

```
Company   | Date       | Prize
Company A | 2011-02-13 | Prize_2
Company B | 2011-01-18 | Prize_2
Company B | 2011-02-13 | Prize_1

Total 3 prizes for "iphone4"
```

What MySQL query would achieve this lookup search?

Comment: If you can, go back and alter your data structure - it is going to cause you problems continually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These really should not be two separate tables, but one table with a company identifying column.

However your situation can be solved in a hackish way:

```
SELECT
  'Company A' AS Company,
  Date, 
  CASE 
    WHEN Prize_1 = 'iphone4' THEN 'Prize_1'    
    WHEN Prize_2 = 'iphone4' THEN 'Prize_2'
    WHEN Prize_3 = 'iphone4' THEN 'Prize_3'
    WHEN Prize_Consolation = 'iphone4' THEN 'Prize_Consolation'
    ELSE NULL
  END AS Prize
FROM `Company A`
WHERE 
  Prize_1 = 'iphone4'
  OR Prize_2 = 'iphone4'
  OR Prize_3 = 'iphone4'
  OR Prize_Consolation = 'iphone4'
/* UNION performs the same query against both tables and combine the results */
UNION
SELECT 
  'Company B' AS Company,
  Date, 
  CASE 
    WHEN Prize_1 = 'iphone4' THEN 'Prize_1'    
    WHEN Prize_2 = 'iphone4' THEN 'Prize_2'
    WHEN Prize_3 = 'iphone4' THEN 'Prize_3'
    WHEN Prize_Consolation = 'iphone4' THEN 'Prize_Consolation'
    ELSE NULL
  END AS Prize
```

FROM `Company B`
    WHERE 
      Prize_1 = 'iphone4'
      OR Prize_2 = 'iphone4'
      OR Prize_3 = 'iphone4'
      OR Prize_Consolation = 'iphone4'

The more appropriate table layout for this design would look like:

```
Table Prizes
---------------
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Date DATETIME,
Company VARCHAR(256),
Prize_Type INT,
Prize_Item VARCHAR(256)

Table Prize_Types
---------------
Prize_Type INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Prize_Description VARCHAR(32)
```

#### Prizes

```
1 | 2012-01-28 08:00:00 | 'Company A' | 3 | 'some prize'
2 | 2012-01-28 08:00:00 | 'Company A' | 2 | 'ipad'
3 | 2012-01-28 08:00:00 | 'Company A' | 1 | 'junky phone'
4 | 2012-01-28 08:00:00 | 'Company b' | 4 | 'iphone4'
```

#### Prize_Types

```
1 | 'Prize 1'
2 | 'Prize 2'
3 | 'Prize 3'
4 | 'Consolation Prize'
```

#### Query this as:

```
SELECT
  Company,
  Date,
  Prize_Item,
  Prize_Description
FROM Prizes JOIN Prize_Types ON Prize_Types.Prize_Type = Prizes.Prize_Type
WHERE Prize_Item = 'iphone4'
```

In fact, you might also want the companies and prize items normalized out into their own tables as well like the Prize_Types.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for the help. Would like to ask, is this still the best data structure if I were also need to do a search on which 'prize_item ' is the most frequent item and list them out according to order?
`exmaple:
Prize   | Total | Lastest occur date |
iphone4 | 100   | 2012-01-30         |
ipad2   | 70    | 2012-01-02         |
tv      | 10    | 2012-01-12         |
`

Comment: @Dennis Yes, you could then do something like `SELECT Prize_Item, MAX(Date) AS most_recent, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM Prizes JOIN Prize_Types ON Prizes.Prize_Type = Prize_Types.Prize_Type GROUP BY Prize_Item ORDER BY Total DESC`